# SwiftUi UIViewRepresentable not getting states updates via EnvironmentObject or ObservedObject

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to implement and receive state updates in SwiftUI but i am not receiving updates from EnvironmentObject or ObservedObject.
I really appreciate any leads of reference.

Below is my sample code from what I am trying to achieve.

```
struct LotMapWrapperView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var data: CarData

    var body: some View {
        LotMapView(data: data)
    }
}

struct LotMapView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @ObjectBinding var data: CarData

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LotMapView>) -> MKMapView {
        MKMapView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LotMapView>) {
        // This is not getting called when store sends didChange :(
        print("Update view")
        print(data.carSlots.count)
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you use LotMapWrapperView?

Comment: Assuming you have `class CarData: ObservableObject {...}`, 
try using `@ObservedObject var data: CarData` in your `LotMapView`.

Comment: ObjectBinding Never made it to SwiftUI 1 I suggest looking at the Apple SwiftUI tutorials

Comment: you are supposed to only supply what it needs, e.g. `LotMapView(count: data.carSlots.count)`